# Mongoose and MongoDB - Can't seem to find documents in my collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Title says it all. I'm trying to learn MongoDB and use the `find()` function to select all documents in my `Comments` collection.

I'm trying to use Mongoose directly in my **routes.js** file, if there's a cleaner convention please let me know, I'm new to NodeJS in general...

---

### routes.js

```
var express = require("express"),
    router = express.Router(),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Comment = require("../models/Comment");

router.get("/comments", function(req, res, next)
{
    mongoose.set("debug", true);
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/Comments");

    var comments = [];

    Comment.find(function(err, array)
    {
        var i = 0;

        for(var o in array)
        {
            comments[i] = o;
            i++;
            console.log("Found comment!");
        }
    });

    res.render("comments", {
        comments: comments
    });

    mongoose.connection.close();
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

### Comment.js (model)

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    message: String,
    posted: Date
});

// Name of the model, the schema, and the collection
module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", CommentSchema, "Comments");
```

---

As you can see in my **routes.js** file, I have debug set to true, so whenever I request the `/comments` resource, I get the following output:

[image: Comments.find() returns undefined]

I can't make sense of this output, other than the fact that the query is reaching the Mongo daemon, so I'm guessing I have either imported my model incorrectly, or I'm just using Mongoose incorrectly. My `Comments` collection is populated with data; I can connect through the Mongo CLI and use `db.Comments.find()` and the documents are shown.

I have omitted my view as not to bloat the question. Thank you all for your time.

---

## Solution:

### routes.js (fixed)

```
var express = require("express"),
    router = express.Router(),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Comment = require("../models/Comment");

mongoose.set("debug", true);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/Comments");  

router.get("/comments", function(req, res, next)
{    
    Comment.find(function(err, dataset)
    {
        res.render("comments", {
            comments: dataset
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

It should be noted that `mongoose.model.find()` is asynchronous, so I had to move my Express render operation within the `find()` callback, otherwise my dataset variable would be rendered before it was populated.

**Comment.js** was errorless and thus was not updated for this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `mongoose.connection.close()` before your async `Comment.find` call completes.

Remove the `mongoose.connection.close()` call and move your `mongoose.connect` call to your app's startup code.  Just leave the created connection pool open for the life of your app rather than opening and closing it with each request.